# algorithmicx and TikZ to mark indentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithmicx

Is it possible to use the `algorithmicx` package and modify the command blocks somehow that I get vertical lines for the indentation? Should this be probably done with Ti*k*Z? (The package `algorithm2e` can do this but I do not use it!)

A simple example I came up with is this one here:

How is it possible to remove the end tags and still have the vertical lines
As soon as I add `\algnotext{EndIf}` the Ti*k*Z is obviously no more drawn and there is no end tag as required?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\keyword}[1]{\textbf{\textsf{#1}}}
\newcounter{scopeCounter}
\newcommand{\decScopeCounter}{\addtocounter{scopeCounter}{-1}}
\newcommand{\incScopeCounter}{\addtocounter{scopeCounter}{1}}

% if blocks
\algblockdefx{If}{EndIf}%
  [1]{%
  \incScopeCounter%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \coordinate (b\thescopeCounter);%
  \keyword{if} #1\hspace{0.5mm}\keyword{:}%
  }%
  {%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \coordinate (e\thescopeCounter);%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \draw[-,very thick]  (b\thescopeCounter) -- (e\thescopeCounter);%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \algorithmicend%
  }

\algcblockdefx{If}{Else}{EndIf}%
  {%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \coordinate (e\thescopeCounter);%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \draw[-,very thick]  (b\thescopeCounter) -- (e\thescopeCounter);%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \coordinate (b\thescopeCounter);%
  \keyword{else:}%
  }%
  {%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \coordinate (e\thescopeCounter);%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \draw[-,very thick]  (b\thescopeCounter) -- (e\thescopeCounter);%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \algorithmicend%
  \decScopeCounter
  }%

\algcblockdefx{If}{Elif}{EndIf}%
  [1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \coordinate (e\thescopeCounter);%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \draw[-,very thick]  (b\thescopeCounter) -- (e\thescopeCounter);%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \coordinate (b\thescopeCounter);%
  \keyword{elif} #1\hspace{0.5mm}\keyword{:}
  }%
  {%
  \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \coordinate (e\thescopeCounter);%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \draw[-,very thick]  (b\thescopeCounter) -- (e\thescopeCounter);%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \algorithmicend%
  \decScopeCounter
  }%

 %\algnotext{EndIf}  %%% UNCOMMENT THIS LINE TO REMOVE end TAGS

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\If{$i\geq maxval$}
    \State $i\gets 0$
\Else
    \If{$i+k\leq maxval$}
        \State $i\gets i+k$
    \EndIf
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Please make your code compilable and as minimal as possible. Thanks.

Comment: no duplicate since I want to use tikz :-)

Comment: I made the code compilable, sorry for the mistakes!

Comment: Oh-uh, Sorry it closed immediately. If you need it to be open please let us know.

Comment: If you want it to be re-opend, you will have to tell us why you refuse `algorithm2e` (which would be the typical approach) and why you do not want the solution from the linked post. If you want someone to do some gratis Ti*k*Z magic for you, it should be clear for what purpose.